# Schema was not assigned?

Tags: sas

The following code had an error message which I am struggling for trying to figure it out. The error message is: "Libname HDMAPP is not assigned".

Thanks for your help in advance!

```
%let tmpschema = HDMAPP;      *schema for transient tables, test-HDMAPP, prod-HDMAPP;  
%let userid    = &uid;           *data mart user;
%let password  = &pw;            *data mart password;
%let memschema = HDMTST;         *schema for member tables;
%let datasrc   = PHEDISRP;       *odbc data source to connect to db2;

proc sql;
 connect to odbc as HDMconnect (datasrc=&datasrc user=&userid password=&password);
    create table &tmpschema..testmp as
    select * from connection to HDMconnect
     (select * from HDMPRD.MEMBER_CMPL);
disconnect from HDMconnect;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means that you do not have a SAS library reference ("libref") defined with the name `HDMAPP`.  Because that is the value of your macro variable `tmpschema`, it's caused by this line in your program:

```
create table &tmpschema..testmp as
```

If you are trying to create a SAS data set, you should have a statement like this before the `proc sql` step:

```
libname HDMAPP 'path-to-local-file-system';
```

Comment: The reason for the error of "Libname HDMAPP is not assigned" is we need allocate memory for the new table &tmpschema..testmp before  create it.